# Script not running. TypeScript Cordova

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I've tried several alternatives, but I can't seem to get this to work or to give me any errors or clues to what I am doing wrong. (Several alternatives being, jquery DOM manipulation, vanilla JS of same, alert as test, console.log as test, etc) Comments removed. There's no output to the appBundle.js (just an empty file), no errors.

index.ts

```
module BlankCordovaApp2 {
    "use strict";

    export module Application {
        export function initialize() {
            app(); // I've also tried moving this out of the module.
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);

        }

        // removed pause and resume for question.

    }

    window.onload = function () {
        Application.initialize();
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
import $ = require("jquery");

function app() {
    console.log('hi');
}
export default app;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "out": "www/scripts/appBundle.js",
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

I tried that "target" just above as ES5 and ES6, not sure which one it should be. Neither worked, nor produced any build or IntelliSense errors.

Note: I can get similar apps working fine in regular JavaScript in and out of Visual Studio.

Comment: in `tsconfig.json` have you tried `"out": "scripts/appBundle.js",`?

Comment: Thanks @DawsonLoudon, but that puts the file in the script directory instead of the www/directory. Eitherway, there's no output to the appBundle, no errors, no behavior.

Comment: I get a whole bunch of build errors when I try your code in es5. If I try es6 I get "TS1204 Cannot compile modules into 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system' or 'umd' when targeting 'ES6' or higher." Are you sure you get no build errors? Can you post your project somewhere?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm thinking that means it's my VS configurations or something since I'm not getting errors and should be. I'll change direction looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `import $ = require("jquery");`

You are using *modules*. You need a module loader e.g. webpack.

> `"out": "www/scripts/appBundle.js",`

Don't use `out` if using modules. More: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't work when I remove the reference to the jQuery module. Looking at the other comments, it seems something is wrong in my configuration of VS or something, because Michael got errors.